# dynamic definition of macro

Tags: c, macros

I need to define function and macro dynamically, for dynamic function the followinf code work fine, but it fail when I try to add macro inside the first one.
Is there a manner to get the needed behavior

```
#define INIT_PATH_FUNCTION(UCI_PATH, DPATH) \
struct ctx *ctx_##_PATH; \
int print##_PATH(char *package) \
{\
    print("package %s \n", package); \
    return 0; \
}\
#define foreach_file_##PATH(path) \
    for (section = print##_PATH(path); \
        section != NULL; \
        section = print##_PATH(path))\

#define PRINT(UCI_PATH, path) print##_PATH(path)


INIT_PATH_FUNCTION(test, "/etc/")
INIT_PATH_FUNCTION(test2, "/root/")
```

Comment: "Dynamic" and "macro" are not going well together. The preprocessing is taking place before any loop is executed. Or even compiled.

Answer (score 0):

> I need to define function and macro dynamically

Then I'm afraid you are destined for dissatisfaction.  You can write a macro whose replacement text contains macro *invocations*, but you cannot produce a macro *definition* by expanding a macro.  Ultimately, it comes down to [paragraph 6.10/2](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.10p2) of the standard, which says, in part

> A preprocessing directive consists of a sequence of preprocessing
>   tokens that satisfies the following constraints: The first token in
>   the sequence is a `#` preprocessing token that (**at the start of
>   translation phase 4**) is either the first character in the source file
>   (optionally after white space containing no new-line characters) or
>   that follows white space containing at least one new-line character.

(Emphasis added.)

Although you can give a macro replacement text that has the form of a macro definition, the replacement text does not satisfy the requirements for being a preprocessing directive of any kind at the start of translation phase 4 (wherein preprocessing directives are executed).  That expansion of the macro produces text of such a form is irrelevant, because it comes too late.

---

Function definitions (and declarations) are another matter, however.  You certainly can produce these via macros if you wish, and this is a reasonable thing to do if you need several distinct functions with a lot of boilerplate code.